# listing elements inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, hash

I am trying to store the values inside a javascript object notation. I have done a bit of programing and got to store all the occureneces in to a string separated with commas, Bt if the term Im trying to find is an array, I get [object object] in return, as it is an array. I want to know how I can store all the items in that array in to a variable separated by commas, here for example if I select "Time", then it should return `Dec 9, 1, 2012`

The part Ive reached returns the value if its a non array, http://jsbin.com/obehog/3/edit

and the depth of the arrays could change, it wont be the same in each case. so going through loop will not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you select "Time", the result is an array, like:

```
[[{
    "term": "Dec 9",
    "Dec_9": [{
        "count": 1,
        "term": "2012"
    }]
}]]
```

if you want a result like `Dec 9, 1, 2012`, you need a method to parse an object to string (or string array), code like:

```
function valuesOfObj(obj, result) {
    result = result || [];
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                arguments.callee(obj[k], result);
            }
        }
    } else {
        result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(valuesOfObj([{
    "term": "Dec 9",
    "Dec_9": [{
        "count": 1,
        "term": "2012"
    }]
}]).join(', ')); // -> Dec 9, 1, 2012
```

the [full demo](http://jsbin.com/exuwet/edit#javascript,live)

By the way, what you done is excellent, there are some other achieve like [jsonselect](http://jsonselect.org/#tryit) and [JSONQuery](https://github.com/jcrosby/jsonquery), Hope useful for you.

Comment: thanks!!!! I really appreciate the help youve done.. Wil check if it works with my realtime input..

Comment: any suggestions on how I can transform this in to a good format so I can write this to an excel file with key values cming once and each value corresponding to that akey goes beneath them..

Comment: and one more thing related to this question, is it possible to select only the relevant content from Time array, like ignoring "Count" field..